# Cannot remove document using obejct id of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I need to remove one document from my database but unable to do it using MongoDB. Here is my query:

```
db.kf_feedback_pro_serv.remove({_id:  ObjectId("575a8a0ae4017ae81400002e")})
```

Using the above query I cannot delete the document.

Comment: Have you tried doing find with this query? Any error you are getting while removing?

Comment: Check whether object Id is correct!!!!

Comment: No error i am getting while removing.

Comment: How do you know that the document is in your collection? Does `db.kf_feedback_pro_serv.findOne()` return any document?

Answer (score 0):

There is no method as `remove`. Use `deleteOne` instead. Also, you can just provide the ID without the `ObjectID(...)`

Try this:

```
db.kf_feedback_pro_serv.deleteOne({_id: "575a8a0ae4017ae81400002e"})
```